# Returning .txt file contents

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file, `Testing.txt`:

```
type,stan,820000000,92

paul,tanner,820000095,54

remmy,gono,820000046,68

bono,Jose,820000023,73

simple,rem,820000037,71
```

I'm trying to create a function that takes this file and returns:

- The average of all the grades (last numbers in the file of each line),
- and the ID (long numbers within file) of the highest and lowest grades.

I know how to get the average but am stuck trying to get the IDs.

So far my code looks like this:

```
#Function:

def avg_file(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = [int(line.split()[2]) for line in f]
        return sum(data)/len(data)


    avg =  avg_file(filename)

    return avg


#main program:

import q3_function

filename = "testing.txt"

average = q3_function.avg_file(filename)

print (average)
```

Comment: if you have blank line (only `\n`) in your file, you will get index exception

Comment: How would you determine the max or min by looking at the file (not using the computer)?

Comment: not using the computer? just by looking at it and grabbing the lowest and highest value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get the desire pairs of ID and score :

```
>>>l= [i.split(',')[-2:] for i in open(filename, 'r') if not i=='\n']
[['820000000', '92'], ['820000095', '54'], ['820000046', '68'], ['820000023', '73'], ['820000037', '71']]
```

Then for calculation the average you can use `zip` within `map` and `sum` functions:

```
>>> avg=sum(map(int,zip(*l)[1]))/len(l)
>>> avg
71
```

And for `min` and `max` use [*built-in functions*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) `min` and `max` with a proper key :

```
max_id=max(l,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
min_id=min(l,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Demo :

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> max(l,key=itemgetter(1))
['820000000', '92']
>>> max(l,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
'820000000'
>>> min(l,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
'820000095'
>>> min(l,key=itemgetter(1))
['820000095', '54']
>>> min(l,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
'820000095'
```

Comment: max and min functions are inverted ;) 820000095 > 820000000. I think the key would be 0, not 1 : `max(l,key=itemgetter(0))`

Comment: @LoïcG. its just am ID!

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood and I took ID for grade. BTW, nice snippet ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think using the python `csv` module would help.
Here is several examples : http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/sorting_csvs.ipynb